# Changing ubuntu system time using java code

Tags: java, ubuntu, time, system

I have a java code written to change the system time but it is not working. java code is compiled and run successfully. Someone please point out what's wrong here.

My java code is:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/priyatam/timesetter.sh");
process.waitFor();
DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());
System.out.println(d.read());   //It gives the output as number of bytes as 83
```

The content of sh file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

date --set="2014-2-20 11:58 AM"

The command 'date --set="2014-2-20 11:58 AM"' works properly in terminal.
Moreover, this sh file works fine when executed from terminal but it won't work through java code.

Anyone have any idea, please share.

Comment: A shell script is not an executable on its own.  You need to invoke a shell and tell it to execute the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should doit like that

```
String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh","/home/priyatam/timesetter.sh" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line=null;

while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {

   log.warn(line);
}

int exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: what is there exception your are getting ?

Comment: there is no exception. but the statement System.out.println(d.read()); is now returning -1

Comment: did you check if the date has been changed or not ?

Comment: i update the cod to reflect the full process can you check it now

Comment: this code is printing the updated time but it is not reflected in the system. did you check if your system time had changed or not? is there any change i need to make to my sh file?

Comment: you need to run the application under root. and if the printline gave you the output that means the shell script is being executed successfully. regarding why it hasnt been reflected i think its a permission issue